# How to parse NSString into BOOL in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, boolean

I am programming in Objective-C for iOS. I would like to parse an object of type NSString into a scalar of type BOOL.

I have a value, and I know that it will either be @"YES" or @"NO", but that YES (or) NO value is NSString and I just want to change NSString into BOOL.

How can I do that?

Please answer me if you know.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I think it's this:

```
BOOL boolValue = [myString boolValue];
```

Comment: what will be the boolValue of "Abdul"? Please suggest me.

Comment: @Abdul Yasin, it will be 0/false. This method is only effective if you know there is a boolean value in the string; e.g. @"1", @"true", @"YES" etc. Other than these, boolValue will always return 0;

Comment: And why `string 0` gives me `nil`, @x4h1d?

Comment: @new2ios, `[@"string 0" boolValue]`  returns `0`, not `nil`,  as I said. You can try it using: `NSLog(@"%zd", [@"string 0" boolValue]);` in __Objective C__ or `let str: NSString = "string 0"
println(str.boolValue)` in __Swift__.

Comment: Sorry, I don't explained well - I mean `[@"0" boolValue]` returns `nil`, @x4h1d. I have expression which returns string 0 (`@"0"`). When I convert it to `BOOL` using `boolValue` I get `nil`.

Comment: @new2ios, are you sure? Because I just tested `[@"0" boolValue]` on both language and it returns as expected. FYI, make sure you use `%zd` to print boolValue.

Comment: :) it's okay. `po` means `print object` and `boolValue` is clearly not an object.

Answer (score 22):

You should probably use `NSString`'s [`-boolValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boolValue). To quote the documentation directly:

> [Returns t]he Boolean value of the receiver’s text. Returns YES on
>   encountering one of "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a digit 1-9—the method
>   ignores any trailing characters. Returns NO if the receiver doesn’t
>   begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number.

That would seem to match your input cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([string isEqualToString: @"YES"])
  foo();
else
  bar();
```

Comment: LOL u beat me by 6 seconds! haha

Comment: That's not the right way. See the other two answers by bschultz and Tommy.

Comment: @H2CO3, eh. The OP said `I exactly know the return value` so I wouldn't go so far as to say it was wrong. Although I agree that `boolValue` seems more robust - and possibly faster by virtue of only needing to inspect the first character... but still.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably best be solved with a conditional, for example:

```
if ([myString isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    myBool = YES;
else if ([myString isEqualToString:@"NO"])
    myBool = NO;
```

Hope this helped you, good luck with your programming.

Comment: This solution is far from correct. There are numerous ways to store a bool in a string, and this only handles a very specific one. Why duplicate the functionality of a method that's already implemented.

Comment: This is too dirty way.

Answer (score 0):

This property should also return true if string is 'true' that's why i think extension is needed...

```
extension NSString{
 var boolValueExtended: Bool {
    get{
        return boolValue ||
            self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).uppercaseString == "TRUE"
    }
}
```

}